# How to use function arguments of payable function for require statement?

Tags: solidity, ether, dapps, payable, require

```
function createCampaign(uint deposit, address ll) public payable{
    dpst = deposit;
    require(msg.value > (40*dpst)/100 wei);
    address newCampaign = address((new Campaign).value(msg.value)(deposit, ll, token_address, 1));
    token_instance.setAllowance(dpst, token_holder, newCampaign);
    deployedCampaigns.push(newCampaign);     
}
```

Here's a piece of my code. In this payable function minimum amount of wei to be sent should be at least 40% of deposit. 
Is the require function implemented correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
require(msg.value > 40 * dpst / 100)
```

To this, in order to avoid precision-loss:

```
require(msg.value * 100 > 40 * dpst)
```

Then to this, in order to avoid overflow:

```
require(msg.value.mul(100) > dpst.mul(40))
```

Then to this, in order to reduce the chances of failure:

```
require(msg.value.mul(10) > dpst.mul(4))
```

Then to this, in order to reduce the chances of failure even more:

```
require(msg.value.mul(5) > dpst.mul(2))
```

BTW, `at least 40%` imples that you can (and should) use `>=` instead of `>`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that works. However, there are a few things to note.

1) You should use [OpenZeppelin's Safemath](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/v2.0.0/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol) for those operations in order to avoid overflow. Your code would look as follows:

```
function createCampaign(uint deposit, address ll) public payable{
    dpst = deposit;
    require(msg.value > (40.add(dpst)).div(100 wei));
```

2) You do not need to specify `wei`. You can simply divide by 100.

3) You do not need to set `dpst = deposit`. You can simply use `deposit` throughout the function.

Comment: But I'm getting error.       transact to CampaignFactory.createCampaign errored: VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value. Debug the transaction to get more information.

Comment: Usage of `add` is wrong here. It should be `mul`. Usage of `div` is not really needed (if I were to use your words, then "You can simply divide by 100").

Comment: And as you might have noticed, `dpst` is not declared in the function, implying that it is a state variable. So possibly this dude needs to record the last deposit used (hence the assignment `dpst = deposit`).

Comment: But although I've declared my function as payable I'm not able to send ether/wei with the function call. Is it a problem with remix ide or what!